# Erro no android studio após update

Tags: android

Realizei update da versão 1.2.0 para a 2.2 e agora sempre que tento criar ou abrir algum projecto aparece :

**Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.debugger.DebuggerManager'**

E não deixa abrir o projecto, alguma solução?

Answer (score 0):

Eu dei uma buscada uma vez pelo mesmo erro e encontrei essa solução em um fórum:

1. Vá até a pasta de instalação do androidStudio exemplo: `c:\user\seuusuario\.AndroidStudioX.X`
2. Renomeia o `.AndroidStudio.X.X` pra qualquer coisa, exemplo: `back_up`
3. Execute o AndroidStudio.
4. Vai perguntar se deseja importar configurações anteriores como no inicio de uma instalação.
5. Escolha a pasta que você renomeou como `back_up`.

Isso é pra resolver...